# Downcast using EL

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, jstl, el

Given the code below:

```
//super class

public class SuperClass {     
     protected String name;     
     public SuperClass(String name){
          this.name = name;
     }     
     public String getData(){
          return "superclass" + name;
     }     
}

//subclass

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {  

private String version;     
     public SubClass(String name) {
          super(name);
     }
     public String getData() {
          return "subclass" + name;
     }
     public String getVersion(){
          return version;
     }
}
```

What i want is to get the version (using getVersion() method of Subclass) in my jsp file using EL and JSTL code:

```
<c:forEach items="${listSuperClass}" var = "element">
     ${element.version}    
</c:forEach>
```

So how to Downcast in this JSTL tag?

Comment: What if you have a `SubClass2`?

Comment: My version attribute is only needed in one subclass, that's why i didn't put it in SuperClass, anyway, i don't see what do you mean by another Subclass

Comment: I hope you know how to handle the situation in which you get an instance from your list that isn't of type `SubClass` and doesn't have that property.

Comment: Yes and and that's why i put this question, i think the solution is in Downcasting and i don't know how to do it using JSLT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to downcast. EL ([note: EL, not JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)!) uses [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to find the method. If it's absent, then it will just throw a `PropertyNotFoundException`.

---

**Update**: if *that* is in turn your *actual* problem (for which you thus incorrectly thought that "downcasting in JSTL" would somehow be the right solution and thus you essentially asked the wrong question), then you should solve it differently:

1. Just don't mix different types in a collection.
2. Put it in a `<c:catch>` and swallow the exception.

   ```html
   <c:catch var="e">
       ${element.version}
   </c:catch>
   ```

   This is however poor design.
3. Determine the instance's actual type inside a `<c:if>`.

   ```html
   <c:if test="${element['class'].simpleName == 'SubClass'}">
       ${element.version}
   </c:if>
   ```

   Better would be to abstract it away  like `abstract Type getType()` returning the desired enum:

   ```html
   <c:if test="${element.type == 'VERSIONABLE'}">
       ${element.version}
   </c:if>
   ```

Comment: Yes it throws this Error: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException, so what i should do to avoid this?

Comment: where should i put abstract Type getType() code? i forget to notice that i mustn't modify my SuperClass code due to our design restrections, cause if i want to modify it i just need to put getVersion()  method in my Superclass to resolve the problem

Comment: If you can't edit the model nor can subclass/wrap it for some unclear reason, then you're out of luck.